# Eloquent ORM (Laravel/PHP) does not use variable?

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, orm

```
 foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value != 'e19f9a5d-fa1c-4209-893f-50b24c299774') {
                        if(Person::where('id', 'like', $firstEightSymbolsOfId . '%')->where('instagramId', '=', $value . '%')->exists()) {
                            error_log('Made it in');
                            error_log($value);
                            return $this->badRequestResponder->validationError(['message' => 'Already in database!']);
                        } else {
                            error_log('Made it in2');
                            error_log($value);
                            $instagramId = $value;
                        }
                    }
```

So when I use this code with a staticly typed value in the eloquent orm statement `where('instagramId', '=', 'someusername')->exists()` the above code goes into first else block and prints "Made it in" & also the content of $value, but when I put in `where('instagramId', '=', $value . '%')` to check dynamicly if the value is in the database already, it goes into the else block and still assigns $instagramId = $value, even if the provided value already exists.

What am I doing wrong here, since I also provide an id in the first where statement and this one works. Has it something to do with the foreach loop or something? I am not that good in php, so it would be nice to get some help.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `%` at the second where ?

Comment: I am so stupid, but that is the answer - I used % there because it is a like statement but here I am trying to make a strict comparison. Tyyy!!!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to search int value by instagramId you can write like that

```php
foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != 'e19f9a5d-fa1c-4209-893f-50b24c299774') {
        if(Person::where('id', 'like', $firstEightSymbolsOfId . '%')->where('instagramId', $value)->exists()) {
            error_log('Made it in');
            error_log($value);
            return $this->badRequestResponder->validationError(['message' => 'Already in database!']);
        } else {
            error_log('Made it in2');
            error_log($value);
            $instagramId = $value;
        }
    }
    
}
```

instead of above , if you want to search with **like** it you can write like that

```php
    
foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
    if ($value != 'e19f9a5d-fa1c-4209-893f-50b24c299774') {
        if(Person::where('id', 'like', $firstEightSymbolsOfId . '%')->where('instagramId', 'like', $value. '%')->exists()) {
            error_log('Made it in');
            error_log($value);
            return $this->badRequestResponder->validationError(['message' => 'Already in database!']);
        } else {
            error_log('Made it in2');
            error_log($value);
            $instagramId = $value;
        }
    }
    
}
```